# Java Denary to Binary Converter Precision Advice

Tags: java, binary, decimal, precision, fractions

I'm still studying java and I'm doing an exercise on this converter. I wrote something as following, it works. A miner problem is when it converts small decimal fraction, it will have the usual precision problem (I understand that, so i make it prints out the fraction it actually used for calculation). I found that most of the online or app converters are dealing this problem using one of the following way:

1. limit the decimal space from user's input and their output
2. output the inaccurate result as is

I want to know how people think about this problem when using a converter with slightly precision problem..does it matter at all? And is there anyway to fix this problem really? Please share your thoughts. Thanks ^^

```
private static void DtoB() {
    int power;
    long i, integer;
    double d, fraction, f;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Plese enter the denary number: ");
    //Break the number
    d = getDouble();    //method that gets the valid input form user
    integer = Math.abs((long)d);
    fraction = Math.abs(d - integer);
    i = integer;        //store the original input for later use
    f = fraction;       //store the original input for later use
    power = 1;

    System.out.println("Integer part: "+i);
    System.out.println("Fraction part: "+f);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("The binary form is: ");

    //Convert the integer part
    //get the largest power of 2 smaller than the number
    while(integer != 0) {
        while(power <= integer/2) { 
        power *= 2;
        }
        System.out.print("1");
        integer -= power;
        //get the rest 1 & 0 till the smallest power of 2
        while(power > 1) {
            power /= 2;
            if (integer < power)
                System.out.print("0");
            else {
                System.out.print("1");
                integer -= power;
            }
        }
    }
    //Convert the fraction part
    if (fraction < 1.0){   //check if there is a fraction part needs to convert
        System.out.print(".");
        while (fraction < 1.0 && fraction != 0) {
            fraction *= 2;
            if (fraction > 1.0) {
                System.out.print("1");
                fraction = (fraction - 1);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("0");
            }
        }
    }
    else if (fraction == 0) {
    }
System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You own the requirement, so it's up to you what's acceptable. If you were writing this for a customer, of course you would ask them.

To avoid problems with floating-point precision, avoid floating-point types altogether.

The `BigDecimal` class exists for doing arbitrary-precision maths in Java.

If, for reasons of study, you don't want to use `BigDecimal`, then you could write similar functionality yourself. Read in your number as a String. Split it on the `.` to get an integer part and a fractional part, and convert these to integers.

You'll also need to keep track of the leading zeros in the fractional part - otherwise `3.51` and `3.00051` would evaluate to the same thing. So, for example:

- `3.51` parses to `i==3, f==51, z==0`
- `42.0022` parses to `i=42, f==22, z==2`

The conversion to binary, I leave up to you as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm storing the fraction part as a double so I don't need to keep track of the zeros, but it causes the problem with precision. So if I read the fraction as a string and convert it to integer before calculation then I can get a more accurate result? I will try that out :)